# Rails 4 + Angular Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a new Rails 4 App where I am attempting to use Angular primarily on the front-end.

I have the following:

Board.rb

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organization
    has_many :warehouses

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :warehouses
end
```

Warehouse.rb

```
class Warehouse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
end
```

In my boards_controller.rb in the create method I call

```
  @board = @organization.boards.build(board_params) # Organizations are a separate model that have many boards
```

where

```
def board_params
  params.require(:board).permit(:date, :organization_id, :warehouses => [:name])
end
```

If I drop a binding.pry at the beginning of the method, the params look like so:

```
 {"board"=>
  {"date"=>"2013-06-02T15:12:16.554Z",
   "warehouses"=>
     [{"name"=>"Tidewater",
      "grades"=>nil,
      "new_grade"=>
       {"name"=>"New Grade",
        "total"=>0,
        "available"=>"2013-06-02T15:12:16.554Z"}},
     {"name"=>"MIT",
      "grades"=>nil,
      "new_grade"=>
       {"name"=>"New Grade",
        "total"=>0,
        "available"=>"2013-06-02T15:12:16.554Z"}}]},
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"boards",
 "organization_id"=>"1",
 "format"=>"json"}
```

however, calling board_params directly responds with:

```
Unpermitted parameters: warehouses
=> {"date"=>"2013-06-02T15:12:16.554Z"}
```

I've seen suggestions to use warehouses_attributes rather than just 'warehouses' in the board_params but this doesn't seem to work either.

I was wondering if anyone has run into a similar problem and if so..how I can adjust my request or controller to accept and build the warehouse object with their respective Board. Perhaps I'm missing a root node in the warehouse objects?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the params. Add this to your Board model. Problem solved.

attr_accessible :warehouses_attributes

Comment: does not work in Rails 4, since strong_params is built in by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need a mix of:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for : warehouses` and renaming your `warehouses` json attribute / parameter to `warehouses_attributes`

I usually add a function in my rails controller to normalize the parameters before saving:

`def normalize_params(form_params)
    form_params[:warehouses_attributes] = form_params.delete :warehouses
    form_params
  end`

Check this for more reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17216